# Is automatic Bluetooth visibility the new standard?

Tags: bluetooth, privacy, user-interface

On most older devices, Bluetooth visibility options may have been enabled by default, but were always able to be controlled by the user.

For example, in Windows 7, you have the following Bluetooth settings with a checkbox at the top that controls visibility:

[image: Windows 7 Bluetooth Settings]

On an Android 12 device, the following Advanced Settings provides the user with a toggle to control visibility:

[image: Android 12 Advanced Bluetooth Settings]

Both of these options will actually disable the visibility of the device as confirmed by scanning visible devices.

On Windows 10 you have a similar settings menu as Windows 7 with a similar checkbox:

[image: Windows 10 Bluetooth Settings]

However, unchecking the box does not prevent visibility if the the following Settings window is open:

[image: Windows 10 Device Settings]

When this window is open, the device is always visible to any nearby device until Bluetooth is turned off entirely or the user closes the window or navigates to another setting option.

I noticed almost identical behavior an Android 13 device.

[image: Android 13]

When Bluetooth is enabled, the device is not automatically visible, but when the Bluetooth settings are opened, the device automatically becomes visible and the visibility cannot be disabled in any advanced settings.

Is this behavior of automatic visibility when viewing Bluetooth settings a new standard for modern devices?

It seems to be a major step backwards when it comes to privacy and security for users as they are unable to access Bluetooth settings to see or modify paired devices without becoming visible to all nearby devices.

Unfortunately, I do not have any additional devices to test this with and maybe it's just individual software user interfaces, but two "modern" devices having almost identical behavior appears to me as some kind of "standard" whether official or unofficial.

Answer (score 1):

This behavior is by design for more recent devices, for reasons of
ease of use.

In general, for recent devices your device will be become visible
to nearby Bluetooth devices when you enter the Bluetooth settings menu.
Older devices may require you to toggle Bluetooth visibility
manually.

Your device only needs to be visible to other devices when you want
to initiate a pairing from some other device. Some devices will
automatically switch it off after a few minutes, to avoid unnecessarily revealing anything about your device or location to other devices.
When it's on, the other device can "see" your device, so it can send
a pairing request.

If you want to initiate pairing from this device, but do not want
your device to be visible to others, you should select the device
to pair from another screen that shows the available devices
(under Windows 10 this is "Add a Bluetooth device" or similar).

Answer (score 0):

Nothing to do with standards. It is all about usability for the user.

That particular screen (regardless of OS) is specifically used to pair a new device.

99 times out of a 100 a user getting to that screen will want to pair a new device and for that device visibility is desired.
(Not for every pairing, some can do without visibility, but with most it goes a lot better/quicker when visibility is on. And some devices, to save battery, only go into pairing mode when they "see" the visibility of the PC/phone, so for those you NEED visibility to be on.)

So it just makes sense to enable it automatically when the user gets into this screen, in stead of saddling the user with the extra step having to do a manual enable of the visibility each and every time he/she wants to pair a new device.